# Sending a new push request for a closed branch reopens the branch with previous commits already there

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm not opening a new branch. I made changes on the branch, pushed the changes, created a pull request, pull request is approved and then merged to the master branch. GitHub closed the branch automatically. All good so far.

My problem is, when I needed to make more(new) changes under the same branch locally (which is not deleted yet) and then push the changes. It opens the closed branch that was closed on GitHub again. That is fine with me but it actually brings the previous changes I did that is merged already back again, with the new changes added to the bottom.

If this PR is approved and merged to the master, will it try to merge the previous changes and the new changes? Or is it for review purposes only for previous changes and it will only merge the new changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will only merge the new commits.

Each commit has a parent commit. This is the only place in the git tree that this commit can ever exist. If you, for example, `rebase` or `cherrypick` a commit then an identical commit with a new parent commit will be created.

The oldest commit that you have already merged has a parent commit that is the commit on the master branch where the branch was created. This is the only place this commit can exist. Since this oldest commit is already merged to this location, nothing happens when this commit is merged again. The second oldest commit has the oldest commit as parent commit, and that commit is on the master branch so the same logic applies to the second oldest and all other already merged commits as well.

A suggestion if you do not mind, I would argue that a cleaner workflow where the PR only shows the new commits is that you delete the branch locally as well after the PR was merged and work in a new branch. Create the new branch with the same name as the deleted branch if the only reason for you wanting to keep working in the same branch is that you want to keep working in a branch with the same name.